# Another Views Partials Inherited

Tags: inheritance, ruby-on-rails-3.1, view, partials

I have an Rails 3.1 app that uses template inheritance and that works great:

```
views
- application
-- _header.html.haml
- special
-- _header.html.haml
```

In the above example, all pages that `render 'header'` take the header partial from `application`, except those views under `special`.  Standard template inheritance in rails 3.1

My question is, say I have another set of views that want to use the `special` header instead of the `application` one?  I could duplicate the `_header` file under the `also_special` folder, but thats not very DRY!

How would I go about using `special`'s partial from a view outside of `special`?

Edit:

The rub being, I'm using the same layout for everything.  Ie.  I have one: `layouts/application.html.haml` file that specifies `render 'header'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a conditional that evaluates your controller for example:

```
<% if params[:controller]=="forums" %>
  <%= render '/special/header' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'header' %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I'm using the same layout in both... I've put more details in the question.

Comment: Thanks @JCorcuera, I was hoping there'd be a slightly cleaner solution, but I think yours is the one.